# rollapply with function rle(x)

Tags: r, data.table, zoo, rollapply

I have time series data as data.table class and each column (observation points) has values that I want to count them within sliding window (30 width). 
I tried to use rle(sort(x)) to count each values within rollapply but it's not working.

for example if I have table like below,

```
dt <- data.frame(v1=c(1,0,1,4,4,4,4,4),v2=c(1,1,1,4,3,3,3,3),
          v3=c(0,1,1,3,3,3,3,2),v4=c(1,1,0,3,3,3,3,3),
       v5=c(1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5))
```

I tried like this;

```
rollapply(dt, 3, function(x) {rle(sort(x))$values; rle(sort(x))$length})
```

but the result is just doesn't make sense.
please give me some direction...

Comment: I don't see any `data.table`'s above. But more importantly it's unclear what you want - please provide desired output.

Comment: sorry for not clear question. the desired output was for each sliding window i wanted to have sorted value with number of appearance (count). I can make my dt into dt1<-data.table(dt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1** Assuming the objective is to get rolling counts of 3 values try the following:

```
m <- as.matrix(dt)
levs <- sort(unique(c(m)))
f <- function(x) table(factor(x, levs))
r <- rollapply(m, 3, f)
```

Here `levs` is 0, 1, ..., 5 so for each application of the function we will get out a vector 6 long witih a count of the 0's, 1's, ..., 5's.  There are 5 input columns so applying such a function to each column gives 5 * 6 = 30 columns of output.

Note that `rollapply` works with matrices or zoo objects, not data frames, so we converted it. Also to ensure that each function application outputs a vector of the same length we convert each input to a factor with the same levels.

Note that:

```
ra <- array(r, c(6, 6, 5))
```

gives a 3d array in which ra[,,i] is the matrix formed by `rollapply(dt[, i], 3, f)`.    That is, in the matrix `ra[,,i]` there is a row for each application of `f` on column i and the columns in that row count the number of 0's, 1's, ..., 5's.

Another possibility is this which gives the same 5 matrices (one per input column) as components of the resulting list:

```
lapply(dt, rollapply, 3, f)
```

For example, consider the following.  Row 1 of the output says that the first application of f on `dt[,1]` has one 0, two 1s and no other values.  This can also be obtained from `r[,,1]` or from 
`lapply(dt, rollapply, 3, f)[[1]]` :

```
> rollapply(dt[, 1], 3, f)
     0 1 2 3 4 5
[1,] 1 2 0 0 0 0  <- dt[1:3,1] has 1 zero and 2 ones
[2,] 1 1 0 0 1 0  <- dt[2:4,1] has 1 zero and 1 one and 1 four, etc.
[3,] 0 1 0 0 2 0
[4,] 0 0 0 0 3 0
[5,] 0 0 0 0 3 0
[6,] 0 0 0 0 3 0
```

**Solution 2**

This says looking at cell 1,1 of the output that the there is one 0 and two 1s in `dt[1:3,1]`.  Looking at cell 2,1 of the output we see that there is one 0, one 1 and 1 four in `dt[2:4,1]`, etc.

```
> g <- function(x) { tab <- table(x); toString(paste(names(tab), tab, sep = ":")) }
> sapply(dt, rollapply, 3, g) # or rollapply(m, 3, g) where m was defined in solution 1
     v1              v2              v3         v4              v5        
[1,] "0:1, 1:2"      "1:3"           "0:1, 1:2" "0:1, 1:2"      "1:3"     
[2,] "0:1, 1:1, 4:1" "1:2, 4:1"      "1:2, 3:1" "0:1, 1:1, 3:1" "1:2, 5:1"
[3,] "1:1, 4:2"      "1:1, 3:1, 4:1" "1:1, 3:2" "0:1, 3:2"      "1:1, 5:2"
[4,] "4:3"           "3:2, 4:1"      "3:3"      "3:3"           "5:3"     
[5,] "4:3"           "3:3"           "3:3"      "3:3"           "5:3"     
[6,] "4:3"           "3:3"           "2:1, 3:2" "3:3"           "5:3"
```

ADDED:  Additional discussion and solution 2.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but it's really hard to interpret the result. what I really want to get is - if I just use above dt data using 5 width sliding window. For v1 column for first sliding window,1's have 2counts,0's 1, 4's 2, in second sliding window, 1's 1, 0's 1, 4's 3 counts. etc. So when I simply run rle(sort(x)) x as simple vector, you get the result sorted values with total counts. That's what I want to have in my sliding window but... I don't know why the rle function is not nicely applied within rollapply function

Comment: The problem with the code in the question is that the function given to `rollapply` returns outputs of different lengths depending on the input values so it can't make the result into a rectangle.  I have added additional discussion and a second solution.

Comment: it's was extremely helpful.  I will try to digest all and let you know if I have some more question regarding your approach.

Comment: Again, thanks for the help. Can I also add some code to extract the values & their max count in each sliding window?

Comment: In solution 2 replace `table(x)` with `sort(table(x))` and then the values and counts will be in the order of count so the last one will be the max.  If you only want the max value and its count then replace `table(x)` with `tail(sort(table(x)), 1)`.  There are other variations depending on what you need.  Just modify `g` appropriately.